# How to set neomutt as default email client in i3?

Tags: email, i3

I've tried the following solution,

1. After creating `~/.local/share/applications/neomutt.desktop` with the following content,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=neomutt
GenericName=neomutt
Icon=neomutt
Exec=neomutt %u
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=false
```

2. I use `xdg-mime` to set handler for `mailto://`

```bsh
$ xdg-mime default neomutt.desktop x-scheme-handler/mailto
$ xdg-mime query default 'x-scheme-handler/mailto'
neomutt.desktop
```

However, there are two issues for the above soulution.

1. `xdg-open mailto:name@email.com` in terminal could start neomutt. But after exiting neomutt, the following messages will be shown,

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: x-www-browser: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: Firefox: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: iceweasel: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: seamonkey: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: mozilla: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: epiphany: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: konqueror: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: chromium: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: chromium-browser: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: google-chrome: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: www-browser: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links2: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: elinks: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: links: command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: lynx: command not found
w3m: Can't load mailto:name@email.com.
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'mailto:name@email.com'
```

And if I have Firefox installed, the Firefox instance would be started and it in turn starts neomutt again.

2. And for emaill address on a webpage

- If Firefox isn't installed, clicking a "mailto://" in Chrome won't have any response.
- If Firefox is installed, clicking a "mailto://" in Chrome will start Firefox which in turn starts neomutt.

Comment: Your issue is not related to i3 in any way. Rather with arch itself imo. Question: why would you create this `.desktop` file ? Did you try to set it up to neomutt itself ?

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the reply! I think it's related to i3 because I don't notice this issue in xfce4. I create this .desktop for two reason. The first is to start neomutt like other desktop applitions in rofi and the second is to make neomutt the default email client via xdg-mime which requires a .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did as with `ranger`:

1. `xdg-mime default neomutt.desktop x-scheme-handler/mailto`
2. create `~/.local/share/applications/neomutt.desktop`

```
# ~/.local/share/applications/neomutt.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Office;Network;Email;
Comment=Simple text-based Mail User Agent
Comment[de]=Einfaches, Text-basiertes Mailprogramm
# change `st -e` to your terminal running cmd
Exec=st -e neomutt %u
Icon=neomutt
Name=neomutt
Name[de]=Mutt
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Now clicking on `mailto:` will open `st` terminal with `neomutt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I notice simply replacing st with a terminal won't work. For xfce4-terminal, `Exec=xfce4-terminal -x neomutt %u` works. And for gnome-terminal, `Exec=gnome-terminal -- neomutt %u` works.